# USB Thumb Drive not recognized in Hyper-V Manager

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012

I have the free, standalone core Hyper-V Server 2012 running on my physical machine. I set up remote management from my Windows 8 client.

When I proceed to create a virtual machine I would like to install the OS from a usb thumb drive but it is not recognized in Hyper-V Manager on my client (when the USB is plugged into the physical server) nor is it recognized in Server Manager under File and Storage Services > Volumes

Is there a role needed to recognize external usb flash drives? Because I think this standalone version is just core Hyper-V role and that's it... but this is such a basic functionality.

Can anybody comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't native USB device support for Hyper-V VMs for a plethora of reasons. The main one is that it would break in live migration and failover scenarios. This is pretty typical of type 1 hypervisors. ESXi doesn't support generic USB devices connected to the host either.

You can work around this by presenting the USB disk as a passthrough device as [outlined in this TechNet blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/hollis/archive/2012/02/21/accessing-usb-drives-in-a-hyper-v-vm.aspx). The linked example uses the GUI, but you can do it all using `diskpart.exe` and the remote Hyper-V Management console on your Hyper-V 2012 server.

Comment: I think this cannot be done in core, diskpart gives me an error when I try to set the disk to offline: "The operation is not supported on removable media"

Same as here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/winserverhyperv/thread/ff546fc8-847c-408c-b2c6-e330b827266e

Comment: can I open disk manager in core or is this this tool added with a role?

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest. If diskpart doesn't work, then disk manager won't either. You may not be able to mark a usb thumb drive as offline, it might only work for actual usb external hard disks. The command to launch disk manager is `diskmgmt.msc`. If you can launch disk manager on core, that's the command that would do it.

Comment: I cannot launch it from core. diskmgmt.msc unrecognized. Guess I'll just use a DVD. Thank you

Comment: ESXi does support passing through USB devices and supports vMotion with them as well. Its the entire reason why you can assign virtual USB controllers to a VM (not VT-d)

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found a solution.

1. Connect to your Hyper-V VM using RDP (not Hyper-V console)
2. Before logging in, enable the USB thumb drive on the RDP client's Local Resources tab.
3. Voila, your USB thumb drive shows on the VM's Windows Explorer

More [here](http://itproctology.blogspot.com/2008/07/remoting-devices-into-hyper-v-child.html).

Comment: This is a good way to use your USB drive, but it is NOT a solution for installing the OS, which is what the question asks about.  You can't RDP to a HyperV VM that has no OS installed on it yet...